# Is Latest Sencha Touch only supporting Windows Phone 8.1 and Not Windows Phone 8.0?

Tags: windows-phone-8, extjs, sencha-touch

I have downloaded the latest Sencha touch SDK from their site. Created a Sample App and deployed it on Windows Phone 8.0. IT was damm Slugish. Later Look at their site which mentions it support to Windows Phone 8.1(IE 11) Support:Link (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/features/). Later I tried it on Windows Phone 8.1, IT works better on Windows Phone 8.1. Is my assumption correct that the sdk only supports Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not related to OS itself but related to Internet Explorer Mobile 10.0.

IE Mobile 11.0 deployed with WP 8.1 is the first mobile IE which truly supports all Sencha Touch features. IE 10.0 has some HTML5 incompatibilities which is not directly related to Sencha Touch. For instance, file upload doesn't work on IE10 mobile regardless of running framework.